# Finding a solution basis of differential equation

Tags: calculus, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Find a solution basis of $$y'=\left[ \begin{matrix}3&-4&-2\\2&-3&-2\\0&0&1\\ \end{matrix} \right]y \,\text{ and find the solution } \Phi \text{ with } \Phi(0) = (1,1,1).$$

I'm preparing for an exam for which I should know how to solve this type of problem. However, I'm not sure what the general approach is.

I know we're going to need the characteristic equation of the matrix and the corresponding eigenspaces, so I figured that out:

The characteristic equation is $$p(t) = -(t-1)^2(t+1),$$
and the eigenspaces are $$E_1 = [(2,1,0), (1,0,1)] \text{ and }E_{-1}=[(1,1,0)].$$

Now my question is the following: Could you please guide me through the rest of this problem, making clear the general approach for these problems?

Sorry for the broad question. Thank you.

Comment: There are several ways to attack this. Are you familiar with matrix exponentials?

Comment: Yes, I have encountered that before :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/744324/55235) answer.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439127/solve-first-order-matrix-differential-equation).

Comment: I just noticed your work. Assuming what you did is correct, you're nearly done. Note the following. If $(\lambda, v)$ is an eigenpair of $A$ then $(e^{\lambda t}v)'=\lambda e^{\lambda t}v=e^{\lambda t}Av=A(e^{\lambda t}v)$, that is, $t\mapsto e^{\lambda tv}$ is a solution to the differential equation. Since you got three linearly independent vectors, the functions $t\mapsto e^{\lambda _it}v_i$ where $(\lambda _i, v_i)$ are eigenpairs, are linearly independent and hence form a basis of solutions.

Comment: Did you mean to write $t\mapsto e^{t\lambda_i}v_i$, Git Gud?

Comment: @rehband At the end? Yes, I just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: So this gives us the following basis $\{t\mapsto e^{t}(2,1,0), t\mapsto e^{t}(1,0,1), t\mapsto e^{-t}(1,1,0)\}$ ?

Comment: Now $\Phi$ is a linear combination of those three basis vectors and we can find its coefficients using the initial value condition by solving a linear system of equations right? Thanks very much for the help btw :)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252868/general-solution-for-a-given-system-of-equations/252892#252892).

Comment: Many thanks Mhenni Benghorbal!

Comment: @rehband That's right. But you should check for typos in the question. The eigenvalues of that matrix aren't what you say they are. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B3%2C4%2C2%7D%2C%7B2%2C3%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D).

Comment: Indeed, I forgot some minus signs. Fixed it now, thank you.